# Unable to locate Android L (Preview) emulator in Android Device Chooser

Tags: android, android-emulator

I had created a sample Android(L Preview) app with minimum and target SDK version as 21.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

In order to test the app I had created Android L emulator as per the below specifications.

Device : Nexus 5

Target : Android L preview

CPU/ABI : Intel Atom x86

Skin WQVGA400

RAM : 2048 VM Heap : 64

Emulation options: Snapshots checked and host GPU unchecked.

When I try to run the application, emulator is not being shown in the Android Device Chooser dialog.

[image]

Do I need to do anything more?

Thanks

Comment: Before running the application i had started the emulator also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For AndroidL you need to write `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `L` not `21`.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="L"
    android:targetSdkVersion="L" />
```

---

From [***Setting Up the Preview SDK documentation***](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html)

You need to do

- compileSdkVersion is set to 'android-L'
- minSdkVersion is set to 'L'
- targetSdkVersion is set to 'L'

---

Set Build target

> Right click on Project -> Property -> Select "Android" section ->
>   Check "Android L (Preview)" into Project Build Target section.
>
> And then clean your project.

Comment: I tried it but am getting error "Manifest attribute 'minSdkVersion' is set to 'L'. Integer is expected." at the first line of Manifest file.

Comment: Got to property of application and set compiled with AndroidL.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, It worked. But when I create a new project i could not see AndroidL under "Compile with" dropdown.

Comment: @ravi Yes you are correct. That might be the reason because L is not released yet.

Answer (score 2):

To run application in AndroidL (Preview) , just update your mainfest with this code.

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Set your minSdkVersion to 11 . 
I use this. and it works

[image]

Comment: But in this case, you can not access L specific APIs.

Comment: you are right Pankaj , what if we want our application to support more android OS , we need to take android sdk minimum as possible.